# Querying an Excel File from C# - No Results

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net, oledb

I have been attempting to query an excel file from C# using an OLEDB connection. There are no runtime errors when the program runs, but it returns no results. I have tried it with different excel files but have gotten a similar result.

edit: The excel file is located in the project directory. If I remove the excel file from the current location the program will get a file not found exception.

```
         private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFileName = "playerData.xls";
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strFileName    + ";Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);           

        dgsResults.DataSource = ds;

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Does anyone know why this returns no results?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the specific data table has to be referenced in the data binding process.  Adding the following line after the fill() method has solved the issue.

```
        da.Fill(ds);
        dgsResults.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //this is the line to be added
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using strFileName in the connStr yet you have not provided the path with it.

Should be along the lines of:

```
string strFileName = @"c:\excel location\playerData.xls";
```